# How to Snap linestyle in Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, brush, linestyle, snapping

Hai, i am a newbie to actionscript.

i am trying to make a brush tool in actionscript 3, where kids can paint colors inside a circle using the brush. i have achieved this using linestyle. Now i want the brush to snap the color when the kid is about to complete(say when they are 95% to complete the painting). How do i know how much the kid has painted on the circle?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How do i know how much the kid has
>   painted on the circle?

You can:

- make your circles and other shapes Sprites to get separate container
- render them into bitmap and count number of non-transparent pixels in it (you should know what number corresponds to 100%)
- since counting pixels is heavy operation (can take hundreds of milliseconds, depending of shape size), you don't want to run it on every frame. I suggest to do it on MOUSE_UP, right after kid finishes next stroke.

How to count pixels:

```
function countPixels(shape:DisplayObject):int
{
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(shape.width, shape.height);
    bd.draw(shape);

    //here you get sequence of ARGB-packed colors in vector
    var pixels:Vector.<uint> = bd.getVector(bd.rect);

    //AFAIK, fastest method to traverse vector is 'for' loop
    var pixel:uint;
    var filledCount:int = 0;
    for (var i:int = pixels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        pixel = pixels[i];
        //pixel is 32-bit ARGB color value, test upper 8 bits (alpha):
        if ((pixel >> 24) > 0) filledCount++;
    }
    return filledCount;
}
```

Run this on filled shape to get total pixel count to compare with.
After pixelCount reaches 95%, you can clear kid's drawing and show filled shape.

Comment: hey got this working... another problem i faced was "kid can repaint with different color". so i used getpixel() to get the pixel color and calculated it. and its working great now :) thanks for the reply :)